# Running an executable from a C++ program in the same process

Tags: c++, process

Is that possible? I'd like an easy access to the executable's memory to edit it. Alternately, when I'm not the administrator, is it possible to edit the executable's memory from another process? I've tried the ptrace library and it fails if I'm not the administrator. I'm on Linux

Comment: Oh god, no. Why would any sane system allow user process to modify other processes' memory?

Comment: i'm not sure i'm full understanding you question. Do you want to access to your own process memory while it's running?

Comment: @Yossarian, editing another process'es memory is possible in both Windows and Linux. Here is an example of code to hack Minesweeper: http://forum.zomgstuff.net/showthread.php?8869-How-To-Game-Hacking-Beginner (works on Windows XP). So that's possible in general, only tends to fail if I don't have administrator's permissions.
Davide, it's not my own process. It's a game and I'd like to access its memory (like the Minesweeper example). I don't have its source code to edit and thus all given suggestions won't do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but this is possible with shared memory.

See here: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what a debugger does. You could look at the code of an open source debugger, e.g. gdb, to see how it works.

Comment: Are you sure that the debugger really changes the client's memory?  Can you point me to the source?  (I'm just wandering, because the way to write into the memory of another process only works under certain (new) Linux kernels - and gdb exists for years now...)

Comment: I wrote a simple C++ program that prints out the value of an int periodically. I run it and attach gdb to it. Then I use gdb to change the value of the int that is being printed. This changes the output of the program.

Comment: An example of the debugger editing another process's memory can be found on pastebin: [link](http://pastebin.com/uF3MFqFh)

Comment: Yes - you are right.  Do you known how the debugger changes the memory of another process?

Comment: No, but in a way one does not need to. One can use the debugger to do the editing if one has the symbol table.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

- Yes - it works: you don't have to be administrator / root, but of course you need the rights to access the process' memory, i.e. same user.
- No - it is not easy

The possibility to write to `/proc/pid/mem` was added some time ago to the Linux kernel.  Therefore it depends on the kernel you are using.  The small programs were checked with kernel 3.2 where this works and 2.6.32 where it fails.

The solution consists of two programs:

1. A 'server' which is started, allocates some memory, writes some pattern into this memory and outputs every three seconds the memory contents which is placed after the pattern is printed.
2. A 'client' which connects via the /proc/pid/maps and /proc/pid/mem to the server, searches for the pattern and writes some other string into the server's memory.

The implementation uses heap - but as long as the permissions allow - it is also possible to change other portions of the other process' memory.

This is implemented in C, because it is very 'low level' - but it should work in C++.  It is a proof of concept - no production code - e.g. there are some error checks missing and it has some fixed size buffers.

## memholder.c

```
/*
 * Alloc memory - write in some pattern and print out the some bytes
 * after the pattern.
 *
 * Compile: gcc -Wall -Werror memholder.c -o memholder.o
 */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

   char * m = (char*) malloc(2048);
   memset(m, '\xAA', 1024);
   strcpy(m + 1024, "Some local data.");

   printf("PID: %d\n", getpid());

   while(1) {
      printf("%s\n", m + 1024);
      sleep(3);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

## memwriter.c

```
/*
 * Searches for a pattern in the given PIDs memory
 * and changes some bytes after them.
 *
 * Compile: gcc -Wall -std=c99 -Werror memwriter.c -o memwriter
 */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int open_proc_file(pid_t other_pid, char const * const sn,
   int flags) {
   char fname[1024];
   snprintf(fname, 1023, "/proc/%d/%s", other_pid, sn);
   // Open file for reading and writing
   int const fd = open(fname, flags );
   if(fd==-1) {
      perror("Open file");
      exit(1);
   }
   return fd;
}

void get_heap(int fd_maps, size_t * heap_start, size_t * heap_end) {
   char buf[65536];
   ssize_t const r = read(fd_maps, buf, 65535);
   if(r==-1) {
      perror("Reading maps file");
      exit(1);
   }
   buf[r] = '\0';
   char * const heap = strstr(buf, "[heap]");
   if(heap==NULL) {
      printf("[heap] not found in maps file");
      exit(1);
   }

   // Look backward to the latest newline
   char const * hl_start;
   for(hl_start = heap; hl_start > buf && *hl_start != '\n'; 
       --hl_start) {}
   // skip \n
   ++hl_start;

   // Convert to beginnig and end address
   char * lhe;
   *heap_start = strtol(hl_start, &lhe, 16);
   ++lhe;
   *heap_end = strtol(lhe, &lhe, 16);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   if(argc!=2) {
      printf("Usage: memwriter <pid>\n");
      return 1;
   }

   pid_t const other_pid = atoi(argv[1]);
   int fd_mem = open_proc_file(other_pid, "mem", O_RDWR);
   int fd_maps = open_proc_file(other_pid, "maps", O_RDONLY);

   size_t other_mem_start;
   size_t other_mem_end;
   get_heap(fd_maps, &other_mem_start, &other_mem_end);

   ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, other_pid, NULL, NULL);
   waitpid(other_pid, NULL, 0);

   if( lseek(fd_mem, other_mem_start, SEEK_SET) == -1 ) {
      perror("lseek");
      return 1;
   }

   char buf[512];

   do {
      ssize_t const r = read(fd_mem, buf, 512);
      if(r!=512) {
         perror("read?");
         break;
      }

      // Check for pattern
      int pat_found = 1;
      for(int i = 0; i < 512; ++i) {
         if( buf[i] != '\xAA' ) 
            pat_found = 0;
            break;
      }
      if( ! pat_found ) continue;

      // Write about one k of strings
      char const * const wbuf = "REMOTE DATA - ";
      for(int i = 0; i < 70; ++i) {
         ssize_t const w = write(fd_mem, wbuf, strlen(wbuf));
         if( w == -1) {
            perror("Write");
            return 1;
         }
      }
      // Append a \0
      write(fd_mem, "\0", 1);
      break;

   } while(1);

   ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, other_pid, NULL, NULL);   

   close(fd_mem);
   close(fd_maps);

   return 0;
}
```

## Example output

```
$ ./memholder
PID: 2621
Some local data.
Some local data.
MOTE DATA - REMOTE DA...
```

## Other interpretation

There is also another interpretation of your question (when reading the headline and not the question), that you want to replace the 'executable' from one process with another one.  That can be easily handled by `exec()` (and friends):

From `man exec`:

> The  exec()  family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows, the methods used for this are named ReadProcessMemory / WriteProcessMemory, you will, however, need administrative rights for this. The same is for linux, as I've said in my comment, no sane system would allow **user** process to modify non-owned memory.

For linux, the only function is [ptrace](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man2/ptrace.2.php). You will **need** to be administrator.

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/92093-readprocessmemory-writeprocessmemory-linux-equivalent.html contains more detailed discussion.

Can you imagine the consequences of allowing process to modify other process memory, without being administrator?

Comment: That is not true: there is no need to be administrator to change other processes memory.  Please have a look at my answer.